# null check not working with ForEach Linq

Tags: c#

I have below class,

```
public class DataCls
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Priority { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
}
```

In below code I'm trying to generate "Key" based on values of "Message" and "Priority".

Values should be "NA", if "Message" and "Priority" are nulls.

Below code is not working and string concatenation is not happening. What's wrong here?

```
 List<DataCls> lstData = new List<DataCls>
       {
           new DataCls {Message="M1", Priority=null, Key=null },
           new DataCls {Message=null, Priority="P1", Key=null }
       };

        lstData.ForEach(a => a.Key = a.Message == null ? "NA" : a.Message + ":" + a.Priority == null ? "NA" : a.Priority);
```

Comment: `ForEach` is not part of Linq. It is a method on the `List<T>` class.

Comment: thanks for pointing this

Comment: Shouldn't this type of logic be handled within the DataCls class? So it knows if It does not have Message and Priority, It should return "NA" when someone gets the Key property?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to use ForEach? you could try something along the lines of `lstData.Select(a => a.Message, a.Priority, Key= $"{a.Message ?? "NA"}:{a.Priority ?? "NA"}")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

brackets help,  it would of been never null at the end because it was getting added to a static string then compared.

```
lstData.ForEach(
   a => a.Key = a.Message == null ? "NA" : 
        a.Message + ":" + (a.Priority == null ? "NA" : a.Priority));
```

but nicer like this

```
lstData.ForEach(
    a => a.Key = a.Message == null ? "NA" : a.Message + ":" + (a.Priority ?? "NA"));
```

though you may actually really intend it to be this

```
lstData.ForEach(a => a.Key = $"{a.Message ?? "NA"}:{a.Priority ?? "NA"}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Put parentheses around the ternaries to control the order of operations. Without the parentheses, C# will evaluate the `+` before it evaluates the `==`. What your `null` check is doing is the equivalent of this:

```
var foo = "Some Value";
var bar = null;
foo + bar == null; // false
```

That is asking C# to first concatenate `"Some Value"` with `null` and then check whether the result is `null`.

## Example

Your final solution could look something like this.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/DFuwij

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<DataCls> lstData = new List<DataCls>
        {
            new DataCls {Message="M1", Priority=null, Key=null },
            new DataCls {Message=null, Priority="P1", Key=null }
        };

        lstData.ForEach(a => { 
            a.Key = a.Message == null ?
                "NA" : 
                a.Message + ":" + (a.Priority == null ? 
                    "NA" : 
                    a.Priority);
        });

        foreach(var d in lstData)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(d.Key);
        }
    }
}

public class DataCls
{
    public string Message
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Priority
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Key
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Output

```
M1:NA
NA
```